# Is it expensive to hold a reference to an object for a lot of instantiations?

Tags: c#, reference, parent

If I have the class Foo

```
public class Foo
{
    List<Doo> dooList = new List<Doo>();
}
```

and the class Doo

```
public class Doo
{
    Foo parent;
}
```

If I instantiate a lot of instances the class `Doo` with a reference to the parent `Foo`, does that slow the computer down a lot?  Is that an inexpensive way to pass needed variables?

EDIT:
the `Foo` Class has about 20 variables/properties, and the `Doo` class has about the same.
There will be anywhere from 5 to 30 instantiations of the class `Foo`, and each `Foo` class has about 10-20 `Doo` classes

Comment: You must give some more details - define "a lot", "slow", and "expensive"...

Comment: Define "a lot of instansiations", and the performance of "a lot" (in terms of slow down); everything is subjective here... is it currently hurting you?

Comment: with those numbers, that's nothing to talk about.  The framework can handle thousands, even millions of references.  So unless you run it on a pentium 2... you'l be fine.

Comment: Not compared to the alternative.  Having to pass an extra argument to a method cost time as well, time that hits the perf of your program for every single call.  Garbage collection can be hidden to some degree thanks to background GC, you can't hide the cost of a method call.  The numbers you give are *very* low, move on with your life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Foo is a reference type (i.e., a class, not a struct), then holding a reference to it costs about the same as holding an int there instead.
Only thing you should keep in mind is that as along as there's a strong reference to an object, the GC won't clear it.

That being said, i find it's usually a bad practice to hold cyclic references. (class A holds a reference to class B, class B holds a reference to class A).
I would recommend to try and eliminate the need for this by utilizing events, or at the very least, using interfaces (Foo implements interface IBoo, Doo holds references to IBoo instead of Foo). Put the methods that Doo needs to call in IBoo, and don't expose the entire Foo class in Doo.

Hope this helps :)